# Google Pay api Integration in adnroid

Tags: android, api, google-pay

I have Followed the official documentation of google for GPay integration, eventhough i dont have a valid payment card added to my Google Id, is IsReadyToPayRequest is showing "TRUE". How can i check if no card is added to Google Id. Please find my code below :

```
    IsReadyToPayRequest request = IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson(isReadyToPayJson.get().toString());
    Task<Boolean> task = paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request);
    task.addOnCompleteListener((Activity) getContext(),
            new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        showGooglePayButton(task.getResult());
                    } else {
                        Log.w("isReadyToPay failed", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please share your `getIsReadyToPayRequest()` function also. From PaymentUtils.

Comment: public static Optional<JSONObject> getIsReadyToPayRequest() {
        try {
            JSONObject isReadyToPayRequest = getBaseRequest( );
            isReadyToPayRequest.put(
                    "allowedPaymentMethods", new 
                  JSONArray().put(getBaseCardPaymentMethod( )));
             isReadyToPayRequest.put("existingPaymentMethodRequired",true);


            return Optional.of(isReadyToPayRequest);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return Optional.empty( );
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in `existingPaymentMethodRequired` with a value of `true`.

See: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/client#isReadyToPay

Note that the behavior of `isReadyToPay` with `existingPaymentMethodRequired` may be different in the `TEST` environment versus `PRODUCTION`. That is, the response for `isReadyToPay` may return `true` in the `TEST` even if you don't have a payment method available.

Comment: If there is no card added also, isReadyToPay is showing true. But when I tried to press the continue button, I am getting a error response as 409,on AutoResolveHelper !       But before all those, I need to check if card is added or not? Is that possible?

Comment: IsReadyToPayRequest JSON object :                                                                  [
  {
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "apiVersionMinor": 0,
    "allowedPaymentMethods": [
      {
        "type": "CARD",
        "parameters": {
          "allowedAuthMethods": [
            "PAN_ONLY",
            "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"
          ],

Comment: "allowedCardNetworks": [
            "AMEX",
            "DISCOVER",
            "INTERAC",
            "JCB",
            "MASTERCARD",
            "VISA"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "existingPaymentMethodRequired": true
  }
]

Comment: Is this in the `TEST` or `PRODUCTION` environment? Like I mention above, `existingPaymentMethodRequired` will generally return `true` in the `TEST` environment. One way to get it to return `false` in the `TEST` environment is to set `allowedAuthMethods` to `["CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]` only.

Comment: it is on `TEST` environemnt! When i set `allowedAuthMethods` to ["CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"] only.  Gpay button is not showing and giving a toast message   that `unfortunately, Google Pay is not available with this device`. eventhough im having gpay already installed on my device.

Comment: is there any way to show  `Add new credit or debit` options on the sheetview which shown by gpay??